# In allegorical depictions of geometry, why show the earth as encircled by a snake?

Tags: art, mathematics, symbols

Various early modern allegorical paintings or engravings show a personification of geometry with a globe of the earth with a snake, and sometimes with a frog. Here are some examples:

(Only a detail of each work is shown, with a link to the full image.)

- Frans Floris the Elder (1519–1570), *Geometry* (1557); also shows a frog with the globe

[image: Floris]

Full image: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Geometry-by-Frans-Floris-1557.jpg

- Maerten de Vos (1532–1603), *Allegory of the Seven Liberal Arts* (1590); also shows a frog with the globe, easier to see in [this](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Maerten_de_Vos_-_Allegory_of_the_liberal_arts.jpg) lower-resolution version

[image: Vos]

Full image: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Marten_de_Vos_Seven_liberal_arts.jpg

- Maerten de Vos (and workshop), *Allegory of the Seven Liberal Arts* (before 1603)

[image: Vos]

Full image:
https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Maerten_de_Vos_(and_workshop)_Allegory_of_the_Seven_Liberal_Arts.jpg

- Engraving by A. Vallée after Maerten de Vos (date unknown); also shows a frog with the globe

[image: Vallée after Vos]

Full image: https://wellcomecollection.org/works/gdxqxekg

- Cornelis Schut (1597–1655), engraving representing geometry and military science (date unknown)

[image: Schut]

Full image: https://wellcomecollection.org/works/rdun94gn

- Laurent de La Hyre (1606–1656), *Allegory of Geometry* (1649)

[image]

Full image: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:La-hyre-geometry.jpg

Although half the examples are from Maerten de Vos, he seems not to have started the practice, and it did not end with him.

The reason for showing a globe of the earth is obvious: **geo**metry. But what about the snake? Was it common to depict the earth with a snake to symbolize geometry? If so, does the snake have a specific symbolic meaning?

Secondarily, what about the frog that appears in the painting by Frans Floris and two of those by Maerten de Vos?

The idea of a snake encircling the world brings to mind [Jörmungandr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%B6rmungandr) (which tended to swamp a lot of searches), but I see no connection between Jörmungandr and geometry. Likewise I can see no connection between other aspects of [serpent symbolism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serpent_symbolism) and geometry. I imagine the snake is not meant to be [Ouroboros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ouroboros), because none of the images show it eating its own tail.

In the Abrahamic religions, serpents can be associated with knowledge (forbidden or not), but there is no snake shown in connection with other forms of mathematical/scientific knowledge such as arithmetic or astronomy in the "seven liberal arts" paintings by de Vos listed above, nor in the separate paintings depicting arithmetic or astronomy by Floris ([1](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Arithmetic,_from_seven_liberal_arts_series_by_Frans_Floris,_1557.jpg), [2](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Frans-Floris-Astronomy-from-the-Seven-Liberal-Arts-1557.jpg)) or La Hyre ([1](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Allegory_of_Arithmetic_by_Laurent_de_La_Hyre#/media/File:Laurent_de_La_Hyre_-_Allegory_of_Arithmetic_-_Walters_371917.jpg), [2](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Allegory_of_Astronomy_by_Laurent_de_La_Hyre#/media/File:Allegory_of_Astronomy_-_Laurent_de_La_Hyre.jpg)). So there appears to be no general connection of snakes with knowledge in these allegories. Also, the celestial globes shown with the personifications of astronomy in the paintings of de Vos and Floris are not shown encircled by snakes, so there appears to be no symbolic connections between the globe and the forbidden fruit.

Similarly, I have found no symbolic connection between frogs and geometry.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "tenuous"? It seems to fit perfectly, the earth as an apple, the lust for knowledge… such connections are numerous and really present themselves? So, why tenuous? Antiquity (greek/Roman) and (Christian) religion are much likelier targets than Nordic myths for the given painters/tiemframe?

Comment: @LangLangC Thanks for the suggestion. I have added explanation pointing out that the snake is not shown in connection with other types of knowledge, only geometry. (BTW, the [forbidden fruit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forbidden_fruit) in Abrahamic religions is not specified to be an apple, though of course it is commonly depicted as such.)

Comment: [This engraving after the Floris paining](https://www.rijksmuseum.nl/nl/collectie/RP-P-BI-6399) has an associated description provided by the Rijksmuseum Amsterdam: "Een pad en een slang proberen langs de ronding van de globe omhoog te klimmen." (A toad and a snake try to climb up the curve of the globe.)

Comment: Could it be a reference to Ophion who may have been the ancient Greek creator god? https://www.ancientgreecereloaded.com/files/ancient_greece_reloaded_website/titans/ophion.php

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphic_Egg